# ¿Como Adjunto mi base de datos de sql server 2012 en un instalador de c# visual studio 2012?

Tags: c#, sql-server, base-de-datos, visual-studio, windows-installer

Bueno en si es lo siguiente, tengo una aplicacion de membresias en c# que maneja reportes y obviamente una Base de Datos, mi pregunta en si es la siguiente como puedo hacer para que cuando el instalador de la aplicacion instale sql server se cree automaticamente la base de datos en la PC donde se desee instalar, he oido algo sobre scripts en el instalador pero no comprendo muy bien si me explican algo es que necesito una respuesta concreta y especifica, de antemanos gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Que SQL Server intentas instalar?

Comment: ¿Crear la base de datos sería sólo la estructura o también popularla? ¿Y qué estrategia pensabas usar si el usuario no tiene instalado el DBMS?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar `InstallShield`, es una aplicación que te permite hace instaladores con Base de datos y además es bastante intuitivo.

Si no puede usar el instalador de Visual Studio, tienes que agregar el archivo `.mdf`al proyecto, y para el `connectionstring`puedes almacenarlo en el `app.config` o en el `usersettings`.

Para poder generar el instalador puedes crear un nuevo proyecto de instalación o ir a:

`Proyecto -> Propiedades -> Publicar`

En el siguiente enlace puede ver un video de referencia donde hacen el proceso antes mencionado: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zd0b9eJOIQ8)

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), que a diferencia de los demas es gratis y podras distribuir tu instalador de manera libre, puedes crear el script (las instrucciones) para la creacion de la base, el cual puedes ejecutar mediante un archivo .bat

```
 @ECHO OFF
ECHO Creando Base de Datos...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysql.exe" -u root --password=pass -P 6666 < "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram\scripts\create-database.sql"
```

Basicamente ejecutas tu programa (en caso de que sea MySQL), pasando la ruta del mismo, seguido le pasas los datos del server `-u` seguido del usuario (en este ejemplo "root") `--password` seguido de la contraseña (pass) `-p` seguido del puerto (6666) y al final `<` seguido de la ruta del `script.sql`

de igual manera puedes crear el `script` y el `.bat` desde el mismo instalador para pasar la ruta seleccionada por el usuario.